# When is a query too big?

Tags: sql, database, performance

I'm monitoring calls and putting them into a database. I'm putting caller, called, start, end in database. There are an average of 70-80 calls a day (none in the weekend), so it comes to 350-400 a week. The program will be used for a long time, so after a year there will be many items in the database.

A part of the program shows the calls in a graph (volume / day) and also in listbox (who called who). For that I'm using a typical "select * from table" to retrieve the info.

When will the query be so big that the user will experience performance loss?

Update:

I need all the info from the table, so a select * was best to use according to some people.

Each row in the database contains 1 int and 4 strings, simple data.

Comment: Load up your database with a few years records and see - it's really the only way to see where your bottlenecks are.  Redgate have some tools to help with data loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should never be a performance problem during the life of the application, even if your volume increases.  **As long as**:

- you have good [indexes](http://odetocode.com/Articles/70.aspx) on the fields your queries use.
- you don't do something really silly in your queries.

**Without good indexes, you will eventually have problems**.  A couple less important bits of advice:

- specify the columns you want, rather than using "Select *"
- make sure you're reporting query isn't being called a thousand times a second or something crazy like that.

Answer (score 6):

Put a limit on it now.

Do you really need the data for all time?  What's reasonable for the graph/list?  30 days?  60 days?  User-selectable?

Though, 20000 calls a year is not a huge data volume.

Also, bad form to SELECT * -- you should always specify the column list you're selecting.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify what your data store is, schema, indexes, etc. So there is very little information to go on.

But, as a general rule (tongue firmly in cheek):

> *When the users start complaining.*

Comment: Um, that's probably a little late in the game. :)

Comment: @Robert: any *real* answer without more information from the OP is too early in the game :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only doing a simple select, then I'm guessing millions of records before someone will notice.

Of course, if you're db server is on a slow machine, that will also hinder it.

Are you doing any Where clauses or Grouping? Any Joins?  If so, are those on Indexed columns?

The best answer would be: **It Depends.**

Answer (score 0):

How long is a piece of string?

This depends on so many factors (including what you deem to be a 'performance loss') that it is impossible to give a firm answer here. You're going to have to test it yourself and see